# Use integer as autofilter criteria

Tags: vba, loops, variables, criteria, autofilter

I'm trying to use a loop variable as autofilter criteria.
The loop is working fine when I put the autofilter criteria manually.
When I try to integrate my variable (i), it is not working anymore.

Column A contains a series of material numbers ranging from 1-115. One by one I need to filter them and calculate the MIN, MAX, AVERAGE,... on column C values. The range for the formulas is the number of rows filtered. This part is working fine.
As I don't want to repeat this code 115 times, I want to use a loop. The loop itself is working fine.
The autofilter should use the value for I (loop counter) in the selection criteria.
This is not working.

```
Dim rijen As Integer
Dim start As Integer
Dim filterA As String
Dim filterB As String
Dim aantal As Integer
Dim i As Integer

range("A2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
aantal = ActiveCell.Value
    
i = 1
Do Until i > aantal
    
    
range("A2").Select
```

' THIS IS THE PART THAT IS NOT WORKING

```
ActiveSheet.range("$A$2:$H$1045876").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=" & i & "
```

'THIS IS WORKING FINE AGAIN

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, A).Select
start = ActiveCell.Row

range("A2").Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
rijen = range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + start - 1
filterA = ("C" & start)
filterB = ("C" & rijen)

range("D2").Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=MIN(" & filterA & ":" & filterB & ")"
 range("E2").Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=MAX(" & filterA & ":" & filterB & ")"
 range("F2").Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=GEMIDDELDE(" & filterA & ":" & filterB & ")"
 range("G2").Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=STDEVA(" & filterA & ":" & filterB & ")"
 range("H2").Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=MIN(RC[-3],(RC[-2]+RC[-1]))"

ActiveSheet.range("$A$2:$H$1045876").AutoFilter Field:=1

i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria1:=" & i & "
```

This is wrapped in quotes, so it is taking it as a literal string value of "& i &".  Just remove the quotes and ampersands.

```
Criteria1:= i
```

You are using .Select way too much.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) should be of use to you.

Any particular reason you are using VBA to insert all of these formulas rather than, say, an Excel table?

Comment: Thx! this is working!

I'm self taught so still learning to optimise my codes. 
I usually record and then 'clean' the code for variable ranges and selections. 

The data set I use are purchase orders so the set will vary each time I run it. This time it is only 115 materials, but the other set contains over 1000 materials and 40k rows. I only want the first row of each material to contain the formuas. 
No idea on how to do this in an Excel table :-)